# Xdebug how to debug cURL call from one application to another

Tags: php, curl, xdebug

I need to debug a call between two applications. First application is doing an HTTP request using cURL to a different application. I can debug the first one but I don't know how to start debugging session for the second application. I can add some parameter to the cURL logic (`XDEBUG_SESSION_START`) but in that case Xdebug is probably treating the first application as `remote_host` (client). Is there a way how to send `remote_host` IP using cURL as it would be hard for me to change the configuration on the server.

Comment: Consider to debug both apps in isolation